# How to run commands via wsadmin from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, quotes, wsadmin

I am creating a powershell script to do a ripple start for a cluster hosted on Windows websphere install.

For testing I was using this:

```
cmd.exe /k '"E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print AdminApp.list()"'
```

This works fine and returns a list of installed apps.

From here I moved to trying to run wsadmin command to get my cluster name for the restart.

```
cmd.exe /k '"E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print cluster = AdminControl.completeObjectName(''cell=ABCD0001Cell,type=Cluster,name=ZZZ,*'')"'
```

But I am getting an invalid syntax error, I assume I have not escaped my quotes correctly?
Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

cmd.exe : Traceback (innermost last):
At line:4 char:1

- cmd.exe /k '"E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print clu ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (innermost last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<input>", line 1
    print cluster = AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell=ABCD0001Cell,type=Cluster,name=ZZZ,*')   ^
  ```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you use `& "E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print cluster = AdminControl.completeObjectName(''cell=ABCD0001Cell,type=Cluster,name=ZZZ,*'')`?

Comment: @NekoMusume & "E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print cluster = AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell=ABCD0001Cell,type=Cluster,name=ZZZ,*')"  returns the same syntax error.
wsadmin.bat : Traceback (innermost last):
At line:6 char:1
+ & "E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print cluster = Adm ...
+ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It seems to be an error with your wsadmin syntax. Try `& "E:\u01\was85\bin\wsadmin.bat"`

Comment: @NekoMusume  Yes this works fine, and so does the test I did with the "print AdminApp.list()".    I think it has something to do with the quotes within the parentheses required for the command.

Comment: @NekoMusume  From the wsadmin prompt in DOS this command works fine.
wsadmin>cluster = AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell=ABCD0001Cell,type=Cluster,name=ZZZ,*')